# JAXB Element With Specific Name Nested Within Another Element of Unknown Name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an `XmlRootElement(name = "Entity")` that contains one known `XmlElement(name = "Header")` 
and another XmlElement of unknown name, but it is known to have an inner `XmlElement(name="label")`

Here are possible Xmls:

```
<Entity>
   <Header>this is a header</Header>
   <a>
     <label>this is element A</label>
     <otherElements/>
   </a>
</Entity>

<Entity>
   <Header>this is a different header</Header>
   <b>
     <label>this is some other element of name b</label>
     <others/>
   </b>
</Entity>
```

Here are my JAXB annotated classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entity")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Entity {
    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    private Header header;

    @XmlElements( {
       @XmlElement(name = "a", type=LabelledElement.A.class), 
       @XmlElement(name = "b", type=LabelledElement.B.class)
    } )
    private LabelledElement labelledElement;

    // constructors, getters, setters...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public abstract class LabelledElement {
     @XmlElement
     private String label;
     @XmlAnyElement
     private List<Element> otherElements;

     public static class A extends LabelledElement {}
     public static class B extends LabelledElement {}
}
```

This was working great! But then I noticed that it isn't only `<a>` and `<b>`

It could be `<c>`, `<asd>` and even `<anything>`...

So listing the `XmlElement(name = "xyz", type = LabelledElement.xyz.class)` is obviously not the right solution.

All I care about is `Entity#getLabelledElement()#getLabel()` no matter what the `LabelledElement` name is.

How to do this? Is this even possible with JAXB?

Comment: I am also a bit stuck in a similar issue during the `unmarshalling`. I am trying to `unmarshal` unknown elements into `Map<String,Object>` but it's not working as expected. I have posted the complete question in the below-provided link. If you get a chance can you please have a look at it and provide your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648941/jaxb-moxy-unmarshalling-assigns-all-field-values-to-mapstring-object-rather-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EclipseLink JAXB Implementation (MOXy), this should work :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entity")
@XmlSeeAlso({LabelledElement.class}) //Might not be necessary
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Entity {
    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    private Header header;

    @XmlPath("child::*[position() = 2]")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    private Map<String,LabelledElement> labelledElementMap;


    public LabelledElement getLabelledElement(){
         return labelledElementMap.values().get(0);
    }
    // constructors, getters, setters...
}
```

The `MapAdapter` class :

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, LabelledElement>> {

    public static class AdaptedMap {

        @XmlVariableNode("key")
        List<LabbeledElement> entries = new ArrayList<LabbeledElement>();

    }

    public static class AdaptedEntry {

        @XmlTransient
        public String key;

        @XmlElement
        public LabelledElement value;

    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, LabelledElement> map) throws Exception {
        AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
        for(Entry<String, LabelledElement> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry = new AdaptedEntry();
            adaptedEntry.key = entry.getKey();
            adaptedEntry.value = entry.getValue();
            adaptedMap.entries.add(adaptedEntry);
        }
        return adaptedMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, LabelledElement> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
        List<AdaptedEntry> adaptedEntries = adaptedMap.entries;
        Map<String, LabelledElement> map = new HashMap<String, LabelledElement>();
        for(AdaptedEntry adaptedEntry : adaptedEntries) {
            map.put(adaptedEntry.key, adaptedEntry.value);
        }
        return map;
    }

}
```

For reference, my solution is inspired by [this link](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this does not help. I am marshalling the Xml into File even though I don't care about the "otherElements" but I need to read the label value.

Comment: @user640853 Sorry it didn't help, could you explain a bit more what result you're expecting when you're marshalling ?

Comment: I need to marshall the Xml as is, meaning all the elements and attributes under the `labelledElement` are kept but I need to read the value of label

`<Entity><Header>header</Header><asd><label>label asd</label><otherElements></otherElements></asd></Entity>`

With your solution, I would lose the `otherElements` element

Comment: @user640853 Changed the answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Switching to MOXy impl is not feasible; however, this answers my question. Thank you

Comment: I am also a bit stuck in a similar issue during the `unmarshalling`. I am trying to `unmarshal` unknown elements into `Map<String,Object>` but it's not working as expected. I have posted the complete question in the below-provided link. If you get a chance can you please have a look at it and provide your suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648941/jaxb-moxy-unmarshalling-assigns-all-field-values-to-mapstring-object-rather-th

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's possible with EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) implementation, which allows you annotate an interface variable providing a Factory class and method to be used when binding XML to Java, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16155520/923509).

**(edited to provide an example of this approach)**
For instance, you instead of having an abstract class LabelledElement, have an **interface LabelledElement**:

```
public interface LabelledElement {
    String getLabel();
}
```

and then have **classes A and B implement it** like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class A implements LabelledElement{

    private String label;

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name="label")
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
}
```

and **Entity class** annotated like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Entity")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Entity {
    @XmlElement(name = "Header")
    private Header header;

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlType(
    factoryClass=Factory.class, 
    factoryMethod="createLabelledElement")
    private LabelledElement labelledElement;

    // constructors, getters, setters...
}
```

Then, as the answer I linked to suggests, you need a **Factory class** like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Factory {

    public A createA() {
        return createInstance(A.class);
    }

    public B createB() {
        return createInstance(B.class);;
    }

    private <T> T createInstance(Class<T> anInterface) {
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(anInterface.getClassLoader(), new Class[] {anInterface}, new InterfaceInvocationHandler());
    }

    private static class InterfaceInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

        private Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
            String methodName = method.getName();
            if(methodName.startsWith("get")) {
                return values.get(methodName.substring(3));
            } else {
                values.put(methodName.substring(3), args[0]);
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, not really! The answer shows how to annotate with JAXB for the same element name but with different types which is the opposite of the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @user640853 see my edited reply as an example of how I'd modify it by using an interface, a Factory class, and MOXy JAXB implementation.